# authorizationUrl on sidebar of gmail addons using appscript

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-addons

I am using Google cloud datastore which is exposed by jersey rest, i have made authentication using oauth2 to access rest APIS.

Now I want to call restful API from my gmail addons to populate some lovs on gmail sidebar.

I have tried oauth2 authentication provided on https://github.com/googlesamples/apps-script-oauth2.

How do i show **authorizationUrl** on sidebar of gmail using gmail Addons?

CODEBASE

**appscript.json**

```
{
  "timeZone": "America/Los_Angeles",
  "dependencies": {
    "enabledAdvancedServices": [{
      "userSymbol": "Gmail",
      "serviceId": "gmail",
      "version": "v1"
    }],
    "libraries": [{
      "userSymbol": "OAuth2",
      "libraryId": "1B7FSrk5Zi6L1rSxxTDgDEUsPzlukDsi4KGuTMorsTQHhGBzBkMun4iDF",
      "version": "24",
      "developmentMode": true
    }]
  },
  "oauthScopes": ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.addons.execute", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.addons.current.message.metadata", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.storage"],
  "gmail": {
    "name": "Gmail Add-on Quickstart",
    "logoUrl": "https://www.gstatic.com/images/icons/material/system/2x/bookmark_black_24dp.png",
    "contextualTriggers": [{
      "unconditional": {
      },
      "onTriggerFunction": "buildAddOn"
    }],
    "primaryColor": "#4285F4",
    "secondaryColor": "#4285F4",
    "openLinkUrlPrefixes": ["https://mail.google.com/"],
    "version": "TRUSTED_TESTER_V2"
  }
}
```

**Code.gs**

```
function buildAddOn(e) {
  var driveService = createOauthService();
  Logger.log('Access'+driveService.hasAccess());     // GETTING FALSE HERE
  Logger.log('Auth URL'+driveService.getAuthorizationUrl()); // GETTING PROPER AUTH URL.
  Logger.log('Token'+driveService.getAccessToken()); // NEED TOKEN TO BE USED ON REST CALL
}

function createOauthService() {
  return OAuth2.createService('drive')
      .setAuthorizationBaseUrl('https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth')
      .setTokenUrl('https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token')
      .setClientId('MY CLOUD CONSOLE CLIENT ID')
      .setClientSecret('MY SECREAT')
      .setCallbackFunction('authCallback')
      .setPropertyStore(PropertiesService.getUserProperties())
      .setScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive')
      .setParam('login_hint', Session.getActiveUser().getEmail())
      .setParam('access_type', 'offline');
      .setParam('approval_prompt', 'force');
}
```

Is this correct way or am i missing something ?

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

One documented way to do this is to return a card from your buildAddOn() function which contains a button configured to launch the authorization sequence.

```
function buildAuthorizeCard() {
  var authorizationUrl = getOAuthService().getAuthorizationUrl();
  var card = CardService.newCardBuilder();
  var section = CardService.newCardSection();
  section.addWidget(CardService.newTextButton()
          .setText("Authorize MyService")
          .setAuthorizationAction(
                CardService.newAuthorizationAction()
                  .setAuthorizationUrl(authorizationUrl)
          ));
  card.addSection(section);
  return card.build();
}
```

You can give that a try.